# Unable to connect Cassandra Cluster in AWS from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I setup Cassandra Cluster Using DataStax AMI in AWS and run the cassandra service. I am trying to connect this cassandra service from another EC2 instance where titan is installed. Titan server version is 0.4.4. I also tried with 0.5.3 but still the same error.
Cassandra is backend storage for the titan .

**Error is**

```
20366 [main] WARN  com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer  - Could not load graph graph. Please check the XML configuration.
20367 [main] WARN  com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer  - GraphConfiguration could not be found or otherwise instantiated: [com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration]. Ensure that it is in Rexster's path.
com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationException: GraphConfiguration could not be found or otherwise instantiated: [com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration]. Ensure that it is in Rexster's path.at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFromConfiguration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:137)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.<init>(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:54)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRexsterApplication.java:99)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.<init>(XmlRexsterApplication.java:47)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.<init>(Application.java:96)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:188)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:355)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:367)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:311)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:121)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1173)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:75)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance(TitanGraphConfiguration.java:25)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFromConfiguration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:119)
```

**Configuration file -**

```
    <rexster>
        <http>
            <server-port>7182</server-port>
            <server-host>0.0.0.0</server-host>
            <base-uri>http://localhost</base-uri>
            <web-root>public</web-root>
            <character-set>UTF-8</character-set>
            <enable-jmx>false</enable-jmx>
            <enable-doghouse>true</enable-doghouse>
            <max-post-size>2097152</max-post-size>
            <max-header-size>8192</max-header-size>
            <upload-timeout-millis>30000</upload-timeout-millis>
            <thread-pool>
                <worker>
                    <core-size>8</core-size>
                    <max-size>8</max-size>
                </worker>
                <kernal>
                    <core-size>4</core-size>
                    <max-size>4</max-size>
                </kernal>
            </thread-pool>
            <io-strategy>leader-follower</io-strategy>
        </http>
        <rexpro>
            <server-port>7180</server-port>
            <server-host>0.0.0.0</server-host>
            <session-max-idle>1790000</session-max-idle>
            <session-check-interval>3000000</session-check-interval>
            <connection-max-idle>180000</connection-max-idle>
            <connection-check-interval>3000000</connection-check-interval>
            <enable-jmx>false</enable-jmx>
            <thread-pool>
                <worker>
                    <core-size>8</core-size>
                    <max-size>8</max-size>
                </worker>
                <kernal>
                    <core-size>4</core-size>
                    <max-size>4</max-size>
                </kernal>
            </thread-pool>
            <io-strategy>leader-follower</io-strategy>
        </rexpro>
        <shutdown-port>7183</shutdown-port>
        <shutdown-host>127.0.0.1</shutdown-host>
        <graphs>
            <graph>
                <graph-name>graph</graph-name>
                <graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
                <graph-location>/tmp/titan</graph-location>
                <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
                <properties>
                    <storage.hostname>ec2-52-22-199-210.amazonaws.com</storage.hostname>
                    <storage.backend>cassandra</storage.backend>
                </properties>
                <extensions>
                  <allows>
                    <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
                  </allows>
                </extensions>
            </graph>
        </graphs>
    </rexster>
```